# Mark mandatory fields on form, if not filled with valid value

Tags: forms, integer, axapta, ax

if you create a new dataset, mandatory fields which are not set yet are marked with a wiggly red line.

it seems, that only string-values ( or several fields, but at least no integers ) are marked this way.

if integer-references are used ( 1-based ), the regarding fields are filled with 0 per default which causes the red line to disappear.

is there any way to leave those fields empty per default?

thanks for hints!

Answer (score 3):

For integer and real fields you could set the `ShowZero` property to No (on the control or extended data type). Then zero values will appear with a red wave line.

For new base enums leave a blank zero enum value (by convention name it None).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics Ax does not have an "null" concept for fields. It uses some "zero" values for all data types - so you need to use some other NoYes field to express what you want if 0 is not empty